# Point multiple domain to one virtual host in Nginx

Tags: nginx, dns

Basically, I want to redirect every domain name to one virtual host, the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) seems very clear.

```
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name domain1.com www.domain.com domain2.com www.domain.com;
      ...
    }
```

However, only the first domain1.com works. The rest, www.domain1.com, domain2.com and www.domain2.com don't work at all. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other settings to input in order to use multiple domains? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the config is right, so you either didn't reload the settings

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

or the domains don't point to the server, check

```
user@host:~$ host domain.com
user@host:~$ host www.domain.com
```

make sure that the IP's match