# Pointing multiple domains to one virtual host with nginx and jwilder/docker-gen

Tags: docker, nginx, virtualhost, docker-gen

I am new to using nginx and am unsure as to what solution I should tackle this problem with.

I would like to have multiple domains pointing to one single virtual host in nginx.
So, for example: the domains `example.one.com` and `example.two.com` would point to virtual host `hub.site.com`.

I am running nginx and nginx-gen (jwilder/docker-gen) as Docker containers. Config settings for nginx are therefore being defined based on the arguments specified in the run command of other Docker containers. For example:

```
docker run -d \
  --restart=unless-stopped \
  --name hub \
  --network local \
  -e VIRTUAL_HOST=hub.site.com \
  -e VIRTUAL_PORT=3000 \
  -e LETSENCRYPT_HOST=hub.site.com \
  -e LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@site.com \
  -e FRONTEND='https://hub.site.com/' \
  site/hub
```

Here, everything with the `-e` flag gets recognized and implemented into the nginx config.

If there's a way to specify multiple domains to point to `hub.site.com` from this run command, it would solve my problem whilst still using the current flow for defining settings for the nginx config.

The only other solution I know of would be directly editing the nginx config and using the method from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342500/point-multiple-domain-to-one-virtual-host-in-nginx). Although that would go against my current flow for defining nginx config settings.

Answer (score 4):

The jwilder/docker-gen is generate docker-compose.yml for [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy)
In the document say:

Multiple Hosts
If you need to support multiple virtual hosts for a container, you can separate each entry with commas. For example, foo.bar.com,baz.bar.com,bar.com and each host will be setup the same.

So you can add multiple domains to a single host by separating them with commas:

```
...
-e VIRTUAL_HOST=example.one.com,example.two.com
...
```